# Sorting by value in a dictionary if the value is a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know that dictionaries aren't sortable, that being said, I want the representation of the dictionary that is sorted upon that value which is a list.  Example:

```
some_dict= {
    "a": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    "b": [1400, 50, 30, 18, 0],
    "c": [800, 30, 14, 14, 0],
    "d": [5000, 100, 30, 50, .1],
    "for fun": [140000, 1400, 140, 140, .42]
}
```

I want to sort by the first item in the list of each.

I tried something like:

```
sorted(some_dict.items(), key = lambda for x in some_dict: some_dict[x][0])
```

but I get invalid syntax.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track, but you can't put a for-loop in a lambda (hence the error):

```
>>> sorted(some_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][0])
[('a', [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), ('c', [800, 30, 14, 14, 0]), ('b', [1400, 50, 30, 18, 0]), ('d', [5000, 100, 30, 50, 0.1]), ('for fun', [140000, 1400, 140, 140, 0.42])]
```

If you want to keep this order in a dictionary, you can use [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects):

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> mydict = OrderedDict(sorted(some_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][0]))
>>> print(mydict)
OrderedDict([('a', [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), ('c', [800, 30, 14, 14, 0]), ('b', [1400, 50, 30, 18, 0]), ('d', [5000, 100, 30, 50, 0.1]), ('for fun', [140000, 1400, 140, 140, 0.42])])
>>> print(mydict['a'])
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Damnit.  So close.  Thank you very much.

Comment: So if I encase it in dict() it will immediately because unsorted again, correct?

Comment: @Faller Yes. But if you want to prevent this, you can use an [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects). I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

`lambda`s are anonymous functions, but they can only execute expressions in Python:

```
lambda pair: pair[1][0]
```

You could also write it verbosely:

```
def sorting_func(pair):
    key, value = pair
    return value[0]

sorted(some_dict.items(), key=sorting_func)
```