# How to sort a list as a value in a dictionary by the first value in each list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a table of which I want to take 3 of the columns, the section name, its start and its end. The code I am using for this is:

```
Contigs = {}
with open('ecoli.gtf', 'rb') as csvfile: # Opens file
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect=csv.excel_tab)
    for row in reader: #Iterates through each row
        if row[0] in Contigs: # Checks if chromosome or contigs id is already in the dict or not and then adds to it the correct start and end information
            Contigs[row[0]].append((row[3],row[4]))
        else:
            Contigs[row[0]] = [(row[3], row[4])]
```

This works absolutely fine but now I want to sort the data so that for each key it starts with the smallest start value working up to the largest so for example a dictionary with:

```
{'chr2':('24','200'),('50','70'),('1','30'),('30','80')}
```

This should be sorted to:

```
{'chr2':('1','30'),('24','200'),('30','80'),('50','70')
```

This is because the start numbers are 1,24,30,50.

I have tried using the sort function but have been unable to get it to work. The code I have used for this include the examples below, the dictionary has been named Contigs:

```
for key, value in Contigs:
    value.sort(key=lambda element: element[0])

Contigs.sort()
```

And the output comes out as

```
In [4]: Contigs.sort()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-12fe6207fe40> in <module>()
----> 1 Contigs.sort()

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'sort'



In [6]: %paste
for key, value in Contigs:
    value.sort(key=lambda element: element[0])

## -- End pasted text --
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-ecd309a55409> in <module>()
----> 1 for key, value in Contigs:
      2     value.sort(key=lambda element: element[0])

ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

i have also checked previous questions on here and this seemed perfect:
[Sorting by value in a dictionary if the value is a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768255/sorting-by-value-in-a-dictionary-if-the-value-is-a-list)

However when I run the code below I get output going diagonally across my screen which are of numbers which are not in my dataset (generally twice the size of the real numbers) as the highest real numbers are around   ('273176', '273178'),
  ('272071', '273178'),   and the numbers the code below provides are ('4639649', '4639651'), ('4638965', '4639651')]}

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> mydict = OrderedDict(sorted(some_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][0]))
>>> print(mydict)
OrderedDict([('a', [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), ('c', [800, 30, 14, 14, 0]), ('b', [1400, 50, 30, 18, 0]), ('d', [5000, 100, 30, 50, 0.1]), ('for fun', [140000, 1400, 140, 140, 0.42])])
>>> print(mydict['a'])
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

An example of some of my real data is:

```
{'chr': [('190', '192'),
  ('190', '252'),
  ('253', '255'),
  ('190', '255'),
  ('337', '339'),
  ('337', '2796'),
  ('2797', '2799')]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contigs is a dict. Iterating through a dict just gives you the keys. In order to get the keys and values, you need to iterate through `dict.items()`:

```
for key, value in Contigs.items():
    value.sort(key=lambda element: int(element[0]))
```

(I've also added a conversion to integer, otherwise 20 will come before 3.)

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks so much and for explaining why int was used.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `contigs.sort()` you cannot sort a dictionary by key.

If you want to print it sorted you have to extract the keys, sort them and then iterate over them

```
theKeys = contigs.keys()
theKeys.sort()
for k in theKeys;
  print contigs[k]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the values of the dict quite easily as follows:

```
my_dict = {'chr': [('190', '192'),
                   ('190', '252'),
                   ('253', '255'),
                   ('190', '255'),
                   ('337', '339'),
                   ('337', '2796'),
                   ('2797', '2799')],
           "xxx": [(100, 25),
                   (12, 24),
                   (17, 800),
                   (35, 19)]}

for key in my_dict:
    my_dict[key].sort()
```

Since `.sort()` is an in-place operation it modifies the lists in-place. Note, however, that you are sorting strings rather than numbers, which would make '1000' sort less than '22', so you would be better-advised to convert the strings to integers as you create the tuples you insert on the list. An alternative would be to prove a key function (or lambda) to sort on the numeric value, using something like

```
    my_dict[key].sort(key=lambda t: int(t[0])
```

Note also that by using a `collections.defaultdict` you can create empty lists for absent keys. Your code would then look like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
Contigs = defaultdict(list) # list is called to create values for absent keys
with open('ecoli.gtf', 'rb') as csvfile: # Opens file
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect=csv.excel_tab)
    for row in reader: #Iterates through each row
        Contigs[row[0]].append((int(row[3]),int(row[4])))
```